# What are all the milestones for the Wii U version?

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

When accomplishing some task in Super Smash Bros. for Wii U, great or small, you will sometimes be congratulated with a message on the screen indicating that you've achieved some Milestone in your progress through the game.

All of the Milestones possible to encounter in the 3DS version of the game have been [documented](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Notice#Super_Smash_Bros._for_Nintendo_3DS) on the internet. However, the Milestones for the Wii U version are lacking. There would be some overlap, of course, but there are differences.

What are the Milestones possible to encounter in the Wii U version of the game?

Answer (score 4):

This is not yet a complete list, and it's based on the European version of the game. The wording for the US version can be different.

### Playing and Clearing

**Smash**

- Started playing Super Smash Bros. for Wii U!
- Battled 10 times now!
- Battled 50 times now!
- Battled 100 times now!
- Battled 200 times now!
- Encountered Mew for the first time! Strange things do happen.

**Smash Tour**

- Played Smash Tour for the first time!
- Played a total of 100 or more turns in Smash Tour!

**Classic**

- Cleared Classic for the first time!
- Cleared Classic with every fighter!
- Cleared Classic at intensity 9.0: Nothing Harder!

**All-Star**

- Cleared All-Star for the first time!
- Cleared All-Star on Hard!
- Cleared All-Star with every fighter!

**Special Orders**

- Cleared an Intense stage in Master Orders for the first time!
- Cleared Crazy Orders for the first time!
- Cleared Crazy Orders after getting through 10 rounds!

**Events**

- Cleared 30 challenges in Solo Events!
- Cleared all challenges in Solo Events!
- Met the reward requirements of all Solo Events challenges!
- Cleared 10 challenges in Group Events!
- Cleared all challenges in Group Events!
- Met the reward requirements for all Group Events challenges!

**Stadium**

- Won 100-Man Smash for the first time!
- Defeated 300 enemies total in Endless Smash!
- 5000 targets and obstacles blown up in Target Blast!
- Got over 400000 points in Target Blast!
- Cleared the 1000m mark in the Home-Run Contest!

**Trophy Rush**

- 1000 blocks blown up in Trophy Rush!
- 5000 blocks blown up in Trophy Rush!
- Obtained 500 trophies in Trophy Rush!

**Online**

- Got a Global Smash Power rating!
- Got a Global Smash Power of over 100000!
- Collected every online profile icon! Pick the one that's right for you!

### Unlocking

**Fighters**

- Unlocked Falco!
- Unlocked Dr. Mario!
- Unlocked Wario!
- Unlocked Mr. Game & Watch!
- Unlocked Lucina!
- Unlocked Dark Pit!
- Unlocked R.O.B.!
- Unlocked Duck Hunt Duo!
- Unlocked all fighters! Now the real battle begins!
- Unlocked the true All-Star solo mode! Find it in Games & More.
- Mewtwo, the reawakened legend, has joined the battle!

**Stages**

- Unlocked the Kongo Jungle (64) stage! Master the mighty Barrel Cannon!
- Unlocked the Smashville stage! You might even get to see K.K. Slider performing live!
- Unlocked the Pokémon Stadium 2 stage! It's a roller coaster of different elements!
- Unlocked the PAC-LAND stage! Guide the fairy home, then go back home yourself!
- Unlocked the Duck Hunt stage! Get into the retro groove!
- Unlocked the Flat Zone X stage! Can you name all seven games?
- Unlocked all stages! Time to learn all 46 in and out!
- Unlocked the Random Stage Switch option! Find it by selecting Smash, then Rules.

**Demos**

- Unlocked a demo of the classic title Earthbound! Play it in Masterpieces!
- Unlocked a demo of the classic title Mario & Yoshi! Play it in Masterpieces!
- Unlocked a demo of the classic title Kirby's Adventure! Play it in Masterpieces!
- Unlocked a demo of the classic title Punch Out!!! Play it in Masterpieces!
- Unlocked a demo of the classic title Dr. Mario! Play it in Masterpieces!
- Unlocked all of the Masterpieces! Now you can really delve into the fighters' origins!

### Collecting

**Songs**

- Collected over 350 songs!
- Collected over 400 songs!
- Collected every song - a smashing playlist!

**Trophies**

- Collected 100 different trophies!
- Collected 200 different trophies!
- Collected 300 different trophies!
- Collected 400 different trophies!
- Collected 500 different trophies!
- Collected 600 different trophies!

There's no milestone for 700 trophies, even though there are more than 700 to be found. There is one for all trophies, but I'm one short so I don't know the exact wording.

**Moves**

- Collected 50 types of custom special moves!
- Collected 100 types of custom special moves!
- Collected 200 types of custom special moves!
- Collected 300 types of custom special moves!

**Equipment**

- Found 30 unique bonus effects for equipment!
- Found 40 unique bonus effects for equipment!
- Found 50 unique bonus effects for equipment!
- Found 60 unique bonus effects for equipment!
- Found 70 unique bonus effects for equipment!
- Found 80 unique bonus effects for equipment!
- Found 90 unique bonus effects for equipment!
- Collected 100 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 200 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 300 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 400 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 500 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 600 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 700 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 800 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 900 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 1000 pieces of custom equipment!
- Collected 10 types of custom headgear!
- Collected 20 types of custom headgear!
- Collected 30 types of custom headgear!
- Collected 40 types of custom headgear!
- Collected 10 types of custom outfits!
- Collected every type of custom outfit! Your body is ready!

Comment: You receive a notification when you collect all custom moves of a fighter but apparently that doesn't make it onto the milestone list.

Comment: What's your source for this? A lot of my milestones have different text, so I suspect there may be different translations for different regions (mine is a NA copy).

Comment: I have unlocked all of these myself, this is the text as it shows up in the milestone list in-game. I have the EU version.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can find at the moment is a work-in-progress [google document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m__qeuhy7UohAKiMKrV4Zz_O4hBUJNU4YaDZiV36ut8/edit#gid=1973043893). There is supposedly a milestone for a score of 330 in endless smash, but no one has confirmed that online.

Comment: There is no achievement for 330 kills in endless smash, but there is for 300. I got 355 on my first try as Link.